# Why can I not maximise the SMART window in gnome-disks?

Tags: gnome, 18.04, gnome-disk-utility

I would like to be able to resize/move/maximise the gnome-disks SMART window freely since I am unable to read the attribute descriptors properly otherwise as shown in the picture: [SMART Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzfIL.png)

To me this seems like quite the obvious oversight and more of a form-over-function thing which is never really liked or required in system tools.

---

Additional Info:

Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Kernel: 4.18.0-041800-generic

gnome-disk-utility 3.28.3

---

Also on an off-note, why did the function to create extended MBR partitions just vanish?

Comment: Try to maximize the window vertically with mouse. If you want to have  maximize button, then report [bug to upstream](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-disk-utility/issues).

Comment: It doesn't even let me drag the window independently. It's sort of locked to the main gnome-disks window…

Comment: Found an open issue: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-disk-utility/issues/63